# Out of local stack trying to test Fibonacci function in Prolog

Tags: prolog, fibonacci

I made two different Fibonacci functions, the first one worked perfectly. Then I tried to simplify it in an intuitive way. I thought it would work but for some reason it says ERROR: Out of local stack every time I test it.

Working version:

```
fibonacci(0,0).
fibonacci(1,1).
fibonacci(N,F) :- N1 is N-1, N2 is N-2, fibonacci(N1,F1), fibonacci(N2,F2), F is F1+F2.
```

Not working version:

```
fibonacci(0,0).
fibonacci(1,1).
fibonacci(N,F) :- fibonacci(N-1,F1), fibonacci(N-2,F2), F is F1+F2.
```

Could someone explain me what is the problem with the second one? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that in your second one you are recursively calling fibonacci/2 with the term `N-1` instead of an integer whose value is N-1.

So, for example if you where calling `fibonacci(3, F)` it would enter in the third clause and call `fibonacci(3-1, F1)` instead of `fibonacci(2, F1)`. It would then enter again in the third clause and call `fibonacci(3-1-1, F1)` and so on.

Note that Prolog uses special operator `is` to perform arithmetic operations. 
The first example is right.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't this be simpler? Define `fibonnaci\3` such that the first two arguments are the two 'seed' elements (normally 1 and 1, though they can be any two positive integers). The third argument is the computed value of that element of the series.

All you have to do is maintain a sliding window as you recurse along the fibonnaci sequence, thus:

```
%
% the public interface predicate
%
fibonnaci( A , _ , A ) .  % 1. return the first element of the series
fibonnaci( _ , B , B ) .  % 2. return the second element of the series
fibonnaci( A , B , C ) :- % 3. all subsequent values are the sum of
  fib_body( A , B , C ) . %    the preceding two elements in the series.

%
% the 'private' worker predicate
%
fib_body( A , B , X ) :-  % 1. first, compute the next element of the series
  X is A + B .            %    as the sum of the preceding two elements.
fib_body( A , B , X ) :-  % 2. on backtracking, shift our window
  C is A + B ,            %    and recurse down to get the next element
  fib_body( B , C , X ) . %    in the series.
```